# Javascript FIle wont display simple code inside html file

Tags: javascript, html

Do I have to setup a javascript file like an html file so it can display the text i put in the

```
document.write("hello world!");
```

I have the `<script> </script>` inside the html but it still won't display the text i ask for

Comment: You should give us more informations, can you post the html and the js code?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```html
<script>document.write("helloWorld")</script>
```

if you want to use javascript you have to put the actual js code into the script tag or link to an external script file.

It is recommended to set up the external file >like your html file< and to link to it inside of an `<script>` tag at the bottom of the html document. The filename could be App.js and you would have to link to it like this `html <script src="./App.js"></script>` (if the file is in the same folder). For more Information on this topic you could read this: [seperation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)(Wikipeda)

Comment: Thank you yes i was missing the "./" in front of the js file name. i haven't tried it with the book I bought but it worked with what i had left over from previous lessons of that same book. Thanks hopefully that was the issue.

Comment: What if i create a js folder inside the root folder (var/www/html/js) ?? Will the src element be ./js/app.js or ./var/www/html/js/ app.js ??

Comment: you can move up one layer by ```../``` and move "down" to folders in your filestructure by referencing them with ```./folder/file``` -  or if even deeper in your structure ```./folder1/folder2/file etc... .